# Phonegap errors

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

New to phonegap / cordova and can't make sense of the following errors I receive in my Eclipse logcat:

```
08-08 17:38:26.563: E/Adreno-ES20(27870): <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
08-08 17:38:26.563: E/Adreno-ES20(27870): <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
08-08 17:38:26.923: W/BindingManager(27870): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 27870
08-08 17:38:27.353: W/ContextImpl(27870): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.phoeteo.phoenet/files
08-08 17:38:27.353: W/ContextImpl(27870): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.phoeteo.phoenet/files
08-08 17:38:27.353: W/ContextImpl(27870): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.phoeteo.phoenet/cache
```

I'm not being lazy, I HAVE Googled and SO'd each of the errors and have come up empty.  Although there are some references to each, none of the situations given seems to apply to mine.

Can anyone help with any of these?

Thanks

**EDIT**

After doing some digging I found the following lines in the Project Folder/Android 5.1.1/android.jar/android.opengl/GLES20.class

```
public static final int GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT       = 0x8CD6;
```

What does this mean and how does it relate to the error message I am seeing?

Comment: Any answer for this question?i have same issue